# How can I make a yml file for multiple images

Tags: docker, yaml

I have a docker file with multiple images created by me, I would like to make a docker compose yml that opens them all when the server is down, but I can't figure out how to do it, I don't know how to add the images to the yml. I thought of something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
    app:
       image:(here I don't know how to add the images, there are 5 of them)
       volumes:
        - ./nombre_archivo.py:ubicacion_archivo.py
       restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what is a `Dockerfile` with multiple images.

But each image is a separate service in the `docker-compose.yaml`, 
Where in your case `app` is the name of the service. 
You can copy `app` section and multiply it as many times as you need.

Example:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
    app:
       image: image-01-name
       volumes:
        - ./nombre_archivo.py:ubicacion_archivo.py
       restart: always
    app-fe:
       image: image-02-name
       volumes:
        - ./nombre_archivo.py:ubicacion_archivo.py
       restart: always
    app-queue:
       image: image-03-name
       volumes:
        - ./nombre_archivo.py:ubicacion_archivo.py
       restart: always
```

Comment: And how would I make it for 5 images? I'm not sure how should I name the 2 extra `app` services

Comment: `app` is just a name `app-fe` is the same just a name, you can pick any name you want instead of `app`, `app-fe` and so on ..., for the other images